# Can the results of a stored procedure be sorted with T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am operating on a MSSQL 2005 database system that has many stored procedures.   One of the stored procedures is a "report" and I want to sort it without editing the stored procedure.  Is there a way to sort the results of a stored procedure on the fly :  something like this:

```
exec spReport 
order by ColumnT
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert into a temporary table. Then, sort from table.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO #table
EXEC spReport

SELECT *
FROM  #table
ORDER BY ColumnT
```

Comment: This will only work if the proc always returns the same columns (and you will need a create table statement). If it does not then look at @Platon's link.

Comment: This doesnt work, as shown here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Comment: @djangofan, did you try it? why you said it's not working? I agree that in this way, you can not do select into, but it more transparent than OPENROWSET. At least, if stored procedure return same column set, I will use INSERT INTO EXEC not OPENROWSET

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. If you know the structure of the resultset, you can build a #tmp table first, insert #tmp exec spReport, then select from the #tmp table with an order by clause. You may even be able to hack something together using OPENQUERY or OPENROWSET, but I would recommend editing spReport either to always use the order you want or to take a parameter and define the order based on the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should fill a temporary table with the result and then sort it.  Here is the link showing how to do the first part:

[How to SELECT * INTO temp table FROM Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)